# Recurrence equation of an algorithm

Tags: recursion, time-complexity

for this algorithm:

```py
def foo ( n ) :
    k = 1
    for i in range ( n ) :
        k *= 2
    for i in range ( k ) :
        n *= n
    return n
def rekursion4 ( n ) :
    if n <= 0 :
    return foo ( 5 )
    return rekursion4 (int ( n / 3 ) ) * foo ( n * n )
```

The recurrence equation T(n) is given as T(n)= T(n/3)+ c1*2 ^(n² ) + c2*n² +c3

I can't understand from where arise c1*2 ^(n² ) and c2*n²

**The operations +, -, *, and / are the elementary operations and are considered with a runtime in O(1). Constant efforts do not have to be calculated exactly but may be summarized by constants c1, c2, . . ..

I thought since we're repeating the instruction k=k*2 n-times and the multiplication is of O(1) it the runtime of this would be in O(c1*n)
and same for the second loop since were repeating n*=n  k-times and the multiplication is of O(1), k=2^n it would be c*2^n (not n²)